# How do I customize a dpc? Google is said to be no longer accepting registrations for Google Partners

Tags: mdm, android-management-api

I read the relevant webpage and learned that it is no longer possible to register partners, does that mean that it is not possible to integrate relevant apis to customize DPC? My company is currently developing MDM software and would like to do this with a custom DPC. If you can't customize the DPC, you have to use the dpc provided by Google, right?

My company wants to implement a custom dpc through an integrated api.

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow should focus on questions about code. Please look at [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) questions. Discussion of the software and professional usage is not on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Android Enterprise no longer allows new registrations for custom DPCs through the Google Play EMM API. New solutions should leverage the [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management), which includes its own DPC -- [Android Device Policy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.work.clouddpc). This approach removes the need for EMM developers to create, update, and manage custom DPCs. You may refer [here](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/register) for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. But I also want to know if our own application can communicate with google dpc for some other work, such as my mobile device can only be used in the local area network, can not connect to the google api server, how do I send the policy to the mobile device?